# update function union type model elm

Tags: elm

I have a model:

```
type Model
    = InitialScreen
    | ErrorScreen Http.Error
    | List NormalRegion
```

and update function:

```
update : Msg -> a -> ( Model, Cmd msg )
update msg model =
    case msg of
        FetchFail e ->
            ( ErrorScreen e, Cmd.none )

        ShowRegions dto ->
            ( GeographiesDecoder.toNormalRegions dto.regions dto.countries, Cmd.none )

        HoverRegion r ->
            ( model, Cmd.none )
```

where toNormalRegions  is

```
toNormalRegions : List Region -> List Country -> List NormalRegion
```

Compiler throws error on update fn:

```
The 1st and 2nd branches of this `case` produce different types of values. - The 1st branch has this type:

    ( Model, Cmd msg )

But the 2nd is:

    ( List NormalRegion, Cmd msg )
```

Is there a way to cast List into Model?

Comment: What about defining a `type alias` for the `List NormalRegion`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a `Model` type constructor named `List` which is conflicting with the built-in `List` type. I suspect you are actually trying to use an actual list of regions, but that is not represented by what you have coded.

I think you would be better served by defining a non-overlapping constructor:

```elm
type Model
    = InitialScreen
    | ErrorScreen Http.Error    
    | Regions (List NormalRegion)
```